# I cannot opt out of emails

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I set all email preferences to off, yet I receive job emails with annoying follow-ups.

Also, there isn't any one-click unsubscribe in those emails. I always have to log in (and then I can’t turn them off, because they are turned off).